# Get browser window size using Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using selenium to get the browser's window size. Which is not the same as the window size.

In JS, we can do this by

```
driver.manage().window().getSize();
```

In Python, all I could find was

```
driver.get_window_size()
```

But this gives the window size, which is not the same as the browser size.

How to get the browser window size in selenium python?

Answer (score -1):

### `get_window_size()`

[`get_window_size()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_window_size) gets the width and height of the current window.

This method is defined as:

```
def get_window_size(self, windowHandle: str = 'current') -> dict:
    """
    Gets the width and height of the current window.

    :Usage:
        ::

            driver.get_window_size()
    """

    if windowHandle != 'current':
        warnings.warn("Only 'current' window is supported for W3C compatible browsers.")
    size = self.get_window_rect()

    if size.get('value', None):
        size = size['value']

    return {k: size[k] for k in ('width', 'height')}
```

and still seems to work ***perfecto***.

- Sample code block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.google.com/'})
  print(driver.get_window_size())
  driver.maximize_window()
  print(driver.get_window_size())
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  {'width': 1050, 'height': 708}
  {'width': 1382, 'height': 744}
  ```